# Infinite loading bar when run npm install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am completely new to topic of Node to be honest, but I can't find the answer for my question. I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my WSL, and want to install some tool called `jscpd` on my WSL. I have already done `apt-get update` and installed npm packages etc. To install `jscpd`, I use `npm install -g jscpd` and this causes showing some loading bar which never ends. Installing another things also does not work. Can you tell me whan can be a problem in it?

Comment: Two things come to my mind. 1. It's a very large download and your network firewall is slowing it down. 2. Your network firewall may be blocking things. I had similar issues where I work until after 5 months they moved me onto a less restrictive network. Run npm install again and just let it go for at least 30 minutes.

Comment: Sadly, it didnt change anything. @Elijah

Comment: If you have an system admin nearby ask them to look at your network traffic and see if it is getting out or doing anything on the call. I don't have any other info to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some time I found the answer - essential was that I am behind company's proxy, and npm does not take info from .bashrc about proxy settings, so you have to set them independently by

`npm config set http-proxy http://proxy_host:port`

`npm config set https-proxy http://proxy_host:port` -> yes, as a https you should write http, not https, this is not figured out why.